# Adding Facebook OpenID to existing account resulting into a new account

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts, facebook

I have been using MyOpenID and my Gmail ID as OpenID providers for a long time, but both MyOpenID and Gmail ID's are blocked in my office, so Stack Overflow login through these open providers is not possible. I have access to a Facebook account. I tried to delete the Gmail OpenID and added my Facebook account as the second OpenID provider, but when I added Facebook as the OpenID provider, it created an all together new account with the same display name. What am I doing wrong? Could you please guide me step-by-step?

Here is a link to my Stack Overflow account I had been using since a long time:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/531321/ag112

Here is a newly created account when I added Facebook as the new OpenID provider:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/807832/ag112

I want to use

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/531321/ag112

and should be able to login using both my MyOpenID as well as the Facebook account.